# Is a pool part of you home?

Tags: discussion

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26629/what-are-some-common-safety-tips-to-have-a-safe-swimming

Yup. Just was busy answering that question when it got closed seconds before I pressed save.. never mind. I didn't need those 10 minutes any way.

So the question is a bit weird- But would it not have been better editing the title and asking a more specific question on how to secure a pool instead of closing it(closing the question)?

I mean we have answered so many question on here before that had several possible outcomes. Why is this one different?

Like this one.

[Why is this box constantly tripping?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9756/why-is-this-box-constantly-tripping/9758#9758)

not even a grammatically correct title? A box cant be tripping. yet it attracted allot of good attention!

I mean that is a perfect example of a question open to discussion. no specifics there.

The poor lady was looking for advice and it jsut got "moved" then "closed" and no body even had a chance to write anything. You guys must be really bored.

How can you say that "fitting pool safety equipment" is not "[home improvements](https://diy.stackexchange.com/)"?

Ahh- back to my question.

According to the FAQ it is.

> The core of this site is around parts of your home that are typically
>   included when you buy or sell it, the structure, utilities, and major
>   appliances.

Oh- I tagged this for discussion because I am not sure what solicited the closure of that question.

Comment: see: http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/594/are-questions-about-pools-considered-on-topic

Answer (score 5):

I voted to close as "Not a Real Question", based on the "overly broad" part of the description of that close reason.  Certainly, there are aspects of pool safety that are within the site scope -- surrounding it with a fence, laying a non-slip surface around the pool, etc. -- but the question didn't ask for them specifically.

Instead, the OP asked for "some tips", without any more indication of what she was looking for in an answer. The question was originally asked on the [Sports Stack Exchange](https://sports.stackexchange.com/), which is in Beta, and is therefore harder to find than [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/), so I think it's safe to say that the OP was more concerned with the physical activity of swimming than with construction of safety features around the pool.

Finally, even with a fence and non-slip surfaces and anything else that we **can** help them with, the best way to ensure that children are safe around a pool is **continuous supervision by someone who is responsible for their safety**.  And that has nothing whatsoever to do with home improvement.

Comment: Seeing as your answer says pretty much as my half-typed one, I'll just up vote yours.

Comment: So if it was about sports.. then why was it moved away from sports. or atleas closed there. A sports mod just though to him self. Oh she means pool safety.. not actaully swimming safely- no cause we are a sports Q&A and not a DIY Q&A. WTF?

Comment: Why wasnt it eddied to reflect that they meant about actually real life swimming in the pool. then move it back to sports.  Never mind. I understand now. Moderator Errors + confused minions.

Comment: It wasn't about sports, that's why it was closed on the sports site.  I'm not sure why it was migrated here. Sometimes mods don't like turning people away, so they try to find a site that *might* be able to offer at least some advice.  Unfortunately, the [don't migrate crap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91411/why-was-this-question-closed-as-off-topic-without-being-migrated/91446#91446) guidance is no longer in effect, so sometimes stuff gets migrated when it should just be closed.